# Unable to save Publication Targets in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Upgraded from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

Want to change Httpupload page URL mentioned in Publication Targets, but while saving it Tridion is throwing error

> 8004D025) Error: Exception of type 'System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException' was thrown.Unable to save Target type (tcm:0-2-65538).SQLUtilities.GetDatabaseConnectionDataStoreDAL.InitDataStoreBroker.InitDataStoreUtilitiesBL.InitDataStoreTargetTypeBL.UpdateTridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.SaveThroughLegacyBL(String)Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs)Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Update(UserContext,String)XMLState.SaveTargetType.Save

Note: We are able to update Component and Pages but unable to update/create new Publication Targets as well as Target Types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely an MSDTC problem. Check if you can reach the database server from the Tridion server using [DTCPing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918331).

***Update***: other people that had similar problems reported that it was caused by their SQL Server cluster and they fact that they needed to open port 135 on their firewall for messages in one direction and ports 1024-5000 for the response messages. Apparently the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator is even better for troubleshooting than DTCPing as it verifies access to a particular database via SA credentials, server and port.

Comment: Thanks Frank, Meanwhile we also checked “Changing DTC security settings” in installation manual, after making the settings same as give the installation manual issue is resolved.  Screen shot in installation manual says that we have to check "Allow Remote Clients" and "Allow remote Administration" but they have not mentioned it in steps.

Comment: Bad luck. New Publication Target added successfully, but while saving new Target Type we are getting new error "Error: New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator."

Comment: Same problem. Could you DTCPing the other machine? Try it both directions. Our infra guys deal with this type of problem quite often, and I've only heard good stories about their experience with DTCPing.

Comment: Issue resolved. Steps mentioned in the "Changing DTC security settings" section in Installation manual where not done on Database server, after doing that issue is resolved. Now we are facing new issue while publishing raising different thread of that. Thanks