# Tridion Copy/Paste In the same org item causes TCM54 Error

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are experiencing a strange issue after upgrading from Tridion 2011 GA to 2011 SP1 HR1.  When doing a copy-paste of components within the same folder we normally get a popup asking if we want to paste with a different name, however, in our case we see an error message as follows:

[image]

```
/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/CopyPasteItem failed to execute. STATUS (500): Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

The only thing that is visible in the Event Viewer logs are warnings, which are expected (because my test VM gets them too).  We don't actually see any errors other than the one in the GUI.

**When copy/pasting components within a folder:**

```
Unable to paste the item into this Folder. 
Name must be unique for items of type: Component within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources  of conflict: tcm:4-81455. 

Error Code: 
0x80040329 (-2147220695) 

Call stack: 
UtilitiesBL.AssertUniqueTitle 
UtilitiesBL.CloneItem 
ComponentBL.Clone 
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.Copy(OrganizationalItem,Boolean) 
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObjectFacade.Clone(UserContext,String,String,Boolean) 
Folder.PasteItem
```

When copy/pasting Pages in Structure Groups:

```
It is not possible to paste this item into a Structure Group.
Name and File name both must be unique for items of type: Page within this Structure Group and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict: tcm:5-82986-64.

Error Code:
0x80040329 (-2147220695)

Call stack:
UtilitiesBL.AssertUniqueTitleAndFileName
UtilitiesBL.AssertUniqueTitleAndFilename
UtilitiesBL.CloneItem
PageBL.Clone
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.Copy(OrganizationalItem,Boolean)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObjectFacade.Clone(UserContext,String,String,Boolean)
StructureGroup.PasteItem
```

As mentioned above, these are normal warnings generated in the Event log, but we should be getting a popup, not the error.

We have tried restarting the server thinking it's a one-off type of quirk, but that didn't help. I understand that "TCM54" as mentioned in the error message refers to code running through COM+.  Can anyone please offer some advice?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this post: [Unable to save Publication Targets in Tridion 2011 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100744/unable-to-save-publication-targets-in-tridion-2011-sp1)

I seem to recall that pasting uses the old (COM based) code like Publication Targets do.